# How to install dlib to my raspberry pi 3?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, dlib

Anytime I try to import dlib in my python code I get "ImportError: No module named dlib". So then I tried typing in "pip3 install dlib" in terminal and the import error still appears when I try to run my code. Then I will type "pip install dlib" it will take forever to finish installing. What can I do to have dlib install in my raspberry pi?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKfiq.png)

Comment: It sounds like you either have multiple virtual environments, and you installed it into one then are trying to run it in the other, or, you're installing the library in Python 2 and are trying to use it in Python 3 (or the other way around). Your use of `pip` and `pip3` suggest the latter. When you run your program, use `python3` instead of `python` when running your program.

Answer (score 1):

First check the version of your python by running `python3 --version`. Then when you install the "dlib" package, run `python3 -m pip install dlib` instead of just `pip3 install dlib`.